# .awaitReactions doesn't await reactions

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to send a `RichEmbed` to the user with a reaction as a button. After a time if user have reacted I do something. Here's my code:

```
var menu = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setTitle("Settings menu")
    .addField('Change the prefix', '(1)')
var menuMessage = msg.channel.send(menu)
    .then(async m => {
        await m.react('1️⃣')

        var filter = (u, r) => {
            u.id == m.author.id && r.emoji.name == '1️⃣'
        }
        m.awaitReactions(filter, {time: 5000})
            .then(collected => {
                console.log(collected.size)
            })
        })
```

I works fine, but no matter what reaction do I add to the message it logs me `collected.size` as 0 which is weird. 
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

ReactionEmojis of numbers are very special. I don't know why, but it only works when you use their unicode name. So, just replace `1️⃣` with `\u0031\u20E3` and it will work fine.

Comment: So I changed them, but it still doesn't work, still logs 0

Comment: All right. It didn't work for me so I thought it was the solution...

Answer (score 0):

In your filter function, `m` variable is equal to the message embed sent by your bot. In your context, if you want to awaitReactions from the user, use the `msg` variable.